# Motorola moto 4g, battery drain, always high media server actitivity

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, motorola-moto-g, system-apps, motorola

I recently bought a motorola moto 4g, and I quickly noticed that the battery is going low very fast! With no use at all, it's going down 15% percent per hour...

The mediaserver is always taking up 50% of the battery, even when I deleted all the apps (really, áll the apps..). I did some restarting, reseting.. Nothing is helping...

Any suggestions??

By the way, sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: Are you on a custom ROM or stock?

Answer (score 0):

A bug in media server seems to causes it
to get stuck in a loop indexing media files.

I've had the same issue and it used up 40% of my battery over 8 hours.

Restart your phone, then do a force stop on anything that might use it. I stopped google play music,  deezer and amazon music, if that fixes it you can disable them.

Seems to have worked for me so far.

Some say its an error on indexing the media on the sd card, you can create a `.nomedia` file to stop media server indexing it. Just add a file called `.nomedia` in the directory you do not want indexed.

This is a very irritating bug and hopefully google will fix soon.

Comment: Is this a documented bug in android? I have no issues with the media service. If it is documented, could you add a link to the documentation around the bug, as it will add to the answer.